# Python improve performance when searching for a string in a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to optimize the performance of a Python script which searches if a string (a class name) is contained in a file. The file contains about 100.000 lines, each line with a class name.

```
def readFile(fileName):
    fileObj = open(fileName, "r")  # opens the file in read mode
    words = []
    lines = fileObj.read().splitlines()
    # Using a for loop to check if word should be qualified as a class
    # (Not included here for brevity)
    for line in lines:        
        line = line.strip()
        words.extend(line.split())

    fileObj.close()
    return words

#Actual array contains about 1000 classes to check
words[] = ["class1","class2","class3"]

# Contains about 100.000 lines
classes = readFile('classes.txt')
for word in words:
   if (word in classes):
   # do something
```

When running the above code, it takes about 60 seconds to complete (including some string concatenation which should not be the bottleneck, I think).
Is there a faster way to search for a string in a file or simply it's a no-go and only a DB can do better?

Comment: What is `readFile`? Please provide a [mcve]. Likely, the problem is that `readFile` returns a list of words. Use a `set` instead. Checking 1000 words in a `set` of words should be practically instantaneous.

Comment: "including some string concatenation which should not be the bottleneck, I think" exactly how are you performing the string concatenation?

Comment: I wonder if it might be more efficient to check as you read the file rather than writing it to a list and then checking against that list.

Comment: peeps, all of this doesn't matter. If `classes` is a hash-based container, a `set`, then this should take no time at all. It clearly is not, almost certainly a `list`

Comment: Something like `for line in open('classes.txt'): if any(word in line for word in words):` should be good enough...

Comment: @Tomerikoo no. that's still polynomial time.

Comment: `lines = fileObj.read().splitlines()` is not the way to do this in Python. Just use `for line in fileObj: ...`

Comment: I really apologize for missing the readFile definition. Just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
classes = set(readFile('classes.txt'))
```

(Or better yet, just return a `set`from your function).

It should then no longer take 60 seconds, it should be practically instantaneous for 1000 words.

The problem is that you are checking:

```
word in classes
```

But since `classes` is a list, that is a linear time operation, so you ultimately have polynomial time. When `classes` is a set, that will be constant time.

Here is an example, using random strings:

```
In [1]: import string

In [2]: import random

In [3]: words = [''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 10)) for _ in range(1000)]

In [4]: classes = [''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 10)) for _ in range(100_000)]

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: for word in words:
   ...:     word in classes
   ...:
1.22 s ± 6.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

You also vaguely mentioned something about concatenating strings. You *may* also be introducing polynomial time behavior if you do that wrong. But you haven't shown that.

Comment: @Tomerikoo sure, the point is still the same.

Comment: Depends on whether there are multiple instances of the same word, which might matter in other problems as the one presented.

Comment: thanks for the awesome advice. Can't believe it just went from 60 seconds to 1 second just with using set(). Thanks!